# Ajax POST to Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I want to post with AJAX to store data in database and I'm using ADO.Net. However, it doesn't working.

Here my code:

**Controller**

```
 [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult InsertScore(ScoresQ scores)
        {
            db.ScoresQs.Add(scores);
            db.SaveChanges();
           
         
           return Json("true", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Model**

```
    public partial class ScoresQ
    {   [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        private DateTime? month = null;
        public DateTime DateCreated
        {
            get
            {
                return this.month.HasValue
                   ? this.month.Value
                   : DateTime.Now;
            }

            set { this.month = value; }
        }
        public Nullable<int> status { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> score { get; set; }
      
    }
```

**AJAX POST**

And this ajax in .js. Not in views

```
function showScore(data) {
    quiz.style.display = "none";
    scoreBlock.style.display = "block";
    scoreBlock.innerHTML = "<p> You scored " + score + " out of " + data.length + "</p>";
    console.log(score);
    if (score < 4) {
        scoreMessage.innerHTML = "<p>Not so good! Time for some revision.</p>";
    }
    else if (score < 8) {
        scoreMessage.innerHTML = "<p>Pretty good! But still room for improvement.</p>"
    }
    else {
        scoreMessage.innerHTML = "<p>Great work! You really know your birds!</p>"
    }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "Home/InsertScore",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { score: score, status: 1},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
    });
    scoreMessage.style.display = "block";
    quizAgain.style.display = "block";
}
```

and here the error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type ScoresQ is not part of the model for the current context.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix the error, I just change the ajax code like this

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "Home/InsertScore",
            dataType: "json",
            data:
            {"score": score, "status": 1},        
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

As error shows problem is in the code where you are adding object into db. share that code for further analyze.

Answer (score 0):

Your model you are sending from JQuery doesnt meet model in Controller.
Try to modify it in this way:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "Home/InsertScore",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {model.month: month, model.DateCreated: date, model.score: score, model.status: 1},
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Success");
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
    });
```

Comment: this ajax code contain in .js, not in views. So, it can't retrieve the model in controller.  The function js not work when I try change that code like your suggestion

Comment: I mean, that JSON object you are sending with ajax to controller must have same fields as your domain model. Otherwise controller cant parse JSON object to Domain model object.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing variables separately in ajax, you need to pass as an object,

Try the below code,

```
var scores = {score: score, status: 1};
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "Home/InsertScore",
        dataType: "json",
        data: scores ,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
});
```